# Using pry 0.9.12.2 with Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows 7 64-bit. There is no color highlighting

Tags: ruby, windows-7-x64, pry

I recently used Rubyinstaller to install Ruby 2.0. I installed Bundler and Pry via rubygems. Pry does no highlighting whatsoever. During a pry session, everything is the same default grey.

I also have 1.9.3p392 installed with Pry 0.9.12. That works fine if I go in the start menu, and click "Start Command Prompt With Ruby (1.9.3)", then a Pry session that I began that way properly highlights.

If I use the "Start Command Prompt With Ruby" (The 2.0.0 version), then a pry session initiated in that has no syntax highlighting. The same result occurs when using cmd.exe, and the Powershell.

I know the snarky, unhelpful answer is just use POSIX-type OS, but this is on my work computer and I can't change that.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Did you install "ansicon" which pry uses for colors on Windows?

Comment: It's a bug, I guess. https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/961